# Different behavior when setting location from onclick vs href (same js in both)

Tags: javascript, html

Why does setting the location in an onlick produce different results than setting it in the href?

```
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript: location='/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage2.aspx?t=1&tpram=20209&amp;Ref%3dhttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fmySite%2fTest%2fTestLocationPage1.html%3ft%3d1%26tpram%3d20209'">tPram will be: 20209</a>

    <a href="javascript: location='/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage2.aspx?t=1&tpram=20209&amp;Ref%3dhttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fmySite%2fTest%2fTestLocationPage1.html%3ft%3d1%26tpram%3d20209'">tPram will be: 20209,20209</a>
```

Chrome dev tools show the first query string parameters as:

```
t: 1
tpram: 20209
Ref=https://localhost/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage1.html?t=1&tpram=20209:
```

while the second shows:

```
t: 1
tpram: 20209
Ref: https://localhost/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage1.html?t=1
tpram: 20209
```

I've tested this in 3 browsers (chrome, firefox, and IE11), and the behavior is the same in all of them, but I don't understand why.

For any “don’t do that” comments or answers, I’m not looking for advice on best practices.

Comment: Also `javascript:` in an "onclick" attribute value means nothing and can be deleted.

Comment: "href" is a property of the element "a", that is a link, and "onclick" is an event definition of an element. Two very different things, will produce different behavior.

Comment: @Gustavo: are you saying that the javascript isn't being executed in the href?  Otherwise it seems to me that javascript is javascript, and when the same code is run the same behavior should be the result.

Comment: There is some steps to js execution, thought is well answered VoronoiPotato. I just made my comment in a generic way so you won't got in trouble again (at list this kind of trouble)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript: location='/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage2.aspx?t=1&tpram=20209&amp;Ref%3dhttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fmySite%2fTest%2fTestLocationPage1.html%3ft%3d1%26tpram%3d20209'">tPram will be: 20209</a>
```

is equivalent to the below snippet as `javascript:` is a break/continue label and doesn't do anything for your onclick event.

```
<a href="#" onclick="location='/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage2.aspx?t=1&tpram=20209&amp;Ref%3dhttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fmySite%2fTest%2fTestLocationPage1.html%3ft%3d1%26tpram%3d20209'">tPram will be: 20209</a>
```

The second snippet gets urldecoded when the javascript is loaded into the URL, and then it gets run, the first example gets decoded AFTER it gets run.

```
    <a href="javascript: location='/mySite/Test/TestLocationPage2.aspx?t=1&tpram=20209&amp;Ref%3dhttps%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fmySite%2fTest%2fTestLocationPage1.html%3ft%3d1%26tpram%3d20209'">tPram will be: 20209,20209</a>
```